# Why is this still optional?

Tags: swift, swift3, option-type

I make a query that returns a NSNumber. I then attempt to cast the `NSNumber` to `String`. For some reason, it always prints/ compares as an optional...but when I check the variables type it says string...Why is it optional? I need it to be a string!

```
let whoseTurn = selectedGame?["currentSender"] 
let whoseTurnAsString: String = String(describing: whoseTurn)
```

Comment: Because the variable `whoseTurn` is an optional type.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov but doesn't the second line cast it to a string?

Comment: no, it does not cast at all, it creates a string describing the variable.

Comment: @luk2302 sure, but when i compare the second variable to a string it always returns false because its an optional for some reason even tho i specified String...

Comment: no, it is not an optional, it is a String containing the phrase Optional(...).

Comment: nevermind, haha...i get it... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whoseTurn is an optional wrapping your NSNumber.  You aren't "casting" it here to a string, you are making a string that "describes" it, and in this case that description includes the fact that whoseTurn is an optional...  If you don't want that you'll need to unwrap it,

```
let whoseTurnAsString: String = String(describing: whoseTurn!)
```

(note the ! at the end)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if let whoseTurn = selectedGame?["currentSender"] as? NSNumber {
    let whoseTurnAsString = "\(whoseTurn)"
    print(whoseTurnAsString)
 }
```

This is the right way to do optional chaining and make sure you are not forcing an optional

Answer (score 0):

This line of code `let whoseTurn = selectedGame?["currentSender"]` will return an optional.

This line of code `let whoseTurnAsString: String = String(describing: whoseTurn)` will return a `String` describing that optional value, which will be a string like this: *Optional(5)* or *Optional(6)*. It describes the value saying that it is an optional.

So you need to unwrap that optional in order to get the wrapped value, you can force unwrap `selectedGame` like this:
`let whoseTurn = selectedGame!["currentSender"]` and then use the normal String initializer like this: `String(whoseTurn)`.

Or, preferably, safely unwrap it like this:

```
if let whoseTurn = selectedGame?["currentSender"] {
    let whoseTurnAsString = String(whoseTurn)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

String can be optional also '?' or '!' indicates optional, check documentation on optionals.

Comment: this does not answer the question, the type is `String`.

Comment: because this is correct, you created "optional string"

Comment: there are not optional strings involved here